# Add rows with specific values in between existing rows

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have hockey data, called `df`

```
structure(list(event_index = 1:57, coords_x = c(80, 53, 31, -56, 
-34, -33, -40, 30, -66, -36, 45, 17, -6, 47, -51, -31, -69, -86, 
-70, 80, 65, -76, -71, 81, -57, 80, 75, 77, -71, -40, -83, 62, 
77, 76, NA, -61, 69, -45, 68, 31, 58, 61, 80, 34, 80, -85, -37, 
-57, 76, 14, 49, -82, -34, -36, -83, -84, -55), coords_y = c(-1, 
14, -30, 17, 26, -23, -37, 17, -32, -18, 25, 17, -38, 21, 28, 
22, 17, 13, 10, -37, -17, 9, 18, -11, 21, -7, 3, 3, -38, 31, 
8, -30, -2, 4, NA, -5, 15, 10, -30, -34, 20, 27, -4, 8, -18, 
19, 32, -21, 0, 40, -4, -30, -24, -28, -2, -3, 34), event_rinkside = c("R", 
"R", "R", "L", "L", "L", "L", "R", "L", "L", "R", "N", "N", "R", 
"L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "R", "R", "L", "L", "R", "L", "R", "R", 
"R", "L", "L", "L", "R", "R", "R", NA, "L", "R", "L", "R", "R", 
"R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "L", "L", "L", "R", "N", "R", "L", "L", 
"L", "L", "L", "L")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -57L))
```

How do I create rows after every single row, leaving me with 57 * 2 (114 rows), but the values in my newly created rows depend on `event_rinkside` column.

- If `event_rinkside` equals `R`, then, I want to insert `82` into `coords_x` and `0` into `coords_y`.
- If `event_rinkside` equals `L`, then, I want to insert `-82` into `coords_x` and `0` into `coords_y`.

I feel like the solution to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46262655/add-blank-rows-in-between-existing-rows) is a good starting points, but I don't know how to incorporate my own conditions:

Here is the solution I'm talking about:

```
library(purrr)
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  map_dfr(rbind, NA) %>%
  mutate(id = rep(df$id, each = 2))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(coords_x = 82 * ifelse(event_rinkside == "L", -1, 1),
         coords_y = 0) %>%
  rbind(df, .) %>%
  arrange(event_index)
```

*How it works:*

In the first step, `mutate` is used to modify an unassigned copy of `df`. The column `coords_x` gets the value of 82; the value is multiplied with -1 if `event_rinkside == "L"` and 1 otherwise. The column `coords_y` gets the value of 0.

In the next step, the unchanged original data frame `df` and the current unassigned and modified copy of it are combined with `rbind`. Here, `.` represents the result of the `mutate` step above. The result of `rbind` has the rows of the original version above the rows of the modified version.

In the last step, `arrange` is used to sort the rows along the values of `event_index`. In this way, each original row is directly followed by the corresponding modified row.

The result:

```
# A tibble: 114 x 4
   event_index coords_x coords_y event_rinkside
         <int>    <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>         
 1           1       80       -1 R             
 2           1       82        0 R             
 3           2       53       14 R             
 4           2       82        0 R             
 5           3       31      -30 R             
 6           3       82        0 R             
 7           4      -56       17 L             
 8           4      -82        0 L             
 9           5      -34       26 L             
10           5      -82        0 L             
# … with 104 more rows
```

Comment: Could you explain the logic leading up to this?

Comment: I understood it after going through it step by step. Sven `mutate`d `coords_x` and  `coords_y` with the desired values : (82, 0) for R and (-82, 0) for L. Then, he attached the original dataset with `rbind` then `arrange` d by event_index to format the dataset in a way I wanted. Really simple, but brilliant

Comment: @NelsonGon I added an explanation.

Comment: @JasonBaik I added an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with r, the my algorithm should work regardless of that. You want to shift the row up to the 2n-1 row. I would create a second array and manually place them in at the specific indexes.

some pseudo code for you (i usually write in python so my pseudo shows it)

```
reinsert(list):
   array_out = [len(list)*2,len(list[0]) // initialize to the desired dimensions 
   array_out[0] = list[0]  /// manually insert first row cause math
   for n in range(0,len(list)):
      array_out[2n-1] = list[n] 
      array_out[2n] = event_rinkside // make a function call or make an ifthen clause to do you logic
   return(array_out)
```

you can insert the newly created rows in the loop or add them after the fact knowing they will all be at even numbered indexes.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to Sven's answer, using `case_when` to distinguish between the possibilities within `event_rinkside`:

```
new_df <- df %>% bind_rows(
  df %>% mutate(
    coords_x = case_when(
      event_rinkside == 'R' ~  82,
      event_rinkside == 'L' ~ -82,
      TRUE                  ~ coords_x
    ),
    coords_y = case_when(
      event_rinkside == 'R' ~ 0,
      event_rinkside == 'L' ~ 0,
      TRUE                  ~ coords_y
    )
  )
) %>% arrange(
  event_index
)
```

If you know the ranges of your variables, it could be simplified into `if_else`s.

Answer (score 0):

My attempt, which is pretty similar to other answers already,

```
df <- df[rep(1:nrow(df), each = 2),] ## Create a duplicate row after each row

df[seq(2,nrow(df),2),] <- df[seq(2,nrow(df),2),] %>% mutate(coords_x = case_when(event_rinkside == "R" ~ 82,
                                                        event_rinkside == "L" ~ -82,
                                                        TRUE ~ coords_x),
                                   coords_y = case_when(event_rinkside == "R" ~ 0,
                                                        event_rinkside == "L" ~ 0,
                                                        TRUE ~ coords_y)
)
```